# Referencing the user's home directory in a Gradle script

Tags: android, windows, gradle

Is there a cleaner way to reference a file in the user's home directory than doing the following in a gradle script? (referencing an Android keystore in this example)

```
homeDir = System.getenv('HOMEDRIVE') + System.getenv('HOMEPATH');
...
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(homeDir + "\\.android\\releaseKeystore.jks")
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I decided in the end to create variables in the gradle.properties in my user directory for the required paths (e.g storeFile file(releaseKeystore)) and reference them in the script. I can't confirm if the answers posted work but roomsg's solution looks correct.

Answer (score 35):

more generic (read: "groovy" & not using "ant")

```
def homePath = System.properties['user.home']
```

Answer (score 29):

Untested code, but how about something like this (might need parentheses around  the "X as File" bit):

```
signingConfigs {
  release {
    storeFile "${System.properties['user.home']}${File.separator}.android${File.separator}releaseKeystore.jks" as File
  }
}
```

Comment: `${System.properties['user.home']}` works like a charm and helps e.g. to set up local Ivy.

Answer (score 9):

Gradle knows the property `gradleUserHomeDir` which references the directory `.gradle` in user's home directory (e.g. on Unixes: ~/.gradle):

```
println project.gradle.gradleUserHomeDir
```

As it's a file object you can simply use `.parent` on it to get user's home directory:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(project.gradle.gradleUserHomeDir.parent + "/.android/releaseKeystore.jks")
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked out perfectly for me in locating the local maven repository `url = uri(project.gradle.gradleUserHomeDir.parent + ".m2") ` . thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ant** for access `user.home` property. Then, you can use Java File API, which is clearer, than path string concatenation.

```
task hello << {
    def homePath = ant.properties['user.home']
    println homePath
    println new File(homePath, "relative/file/path.txt")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to setup system-debug-keystore-path, you can use the following code lines.

This works on both MacOS and Windows.

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile "${System.properties['user.home']}${File.separator}.android${File.separator}debug.keystore" as File
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            storePassword 'android'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
buildTypes {
        ...
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }
    }
```